# A problem involving functions and horizontal asymptotes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let
$$f(x) = \frac{x - \sqrt{3}}{x\sqrt{3} + 1}.$$
What is $f^{2012}(x)$, where $f^{2012}$ is the function we get when we compose $f$ with itself 2012 times?

what does it mean by $f^{2012}$ I still don't understand...

Comment: Write $f(x)$ using the partial fraction decomposition you found in (a), and add a polynomial.  In what cases would that sum have a limit of 0 at ∞?

Comment: It says what it means in your question: "compose $f$ with itself 2012 times". For example, $f^2(x) = f(f(x))$ and $f^3(x) = f(f(f(x)))$, and so on...

Comment: okay thanks :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$f^{(1)}=f(x) = \frac{x - \sqrt{3}}{x\sqrt{3} + 1}$$
$$f^{(2)}=f(f^{(1)})=\frac{x+\sqrt{3}}{1-\sqrt{3} x}$$
$$f^{(3)}=f(f^{(2)})=x$$ $$f^{(4)}=f(f^{(3)})=\frac{x-\sqrt{3}}{x\sqrt{3} +1}=f^{(1)}$$